# why system login is denied in cx_Oracle.SYSDBA mode

Tags: python, oracle, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle 12c through cx_Oracle module.
Login using following code works where no mode is mentioned in cx_Oracle.connect method

```
import cx_Oracle                                                                
ip = 'ip'                                                             
port='1521'                                                                    
SID='orcl'                                                                     
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)                                     
db = cx_Oracle.connect('system', 'password', dsn_tns)
```

but for following way it shows invalid login error for cx_Oracle.SYSDBA mode.

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('system', 'password', dsn_tns, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

Error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

What am I missing here ?? credentials are same. 
I tried login manually as follows and is successful

```
>sqlplus system/password as sysdba
```

Comment: What happens if you use db = cx_Oracle.connect('system', 'password', None, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA) . Does it connect you then?

Comment: How can it James. If dsn_tns is removed what IP and port will it connect.

Comment: It should try and connect to the database on your local machine specified by your environment variables. Notice that in your sqlplus connection command you don't specify the connection details there either

Comment: Try with the username 'sys', not 'system'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you connect as user **sys**, you need to use the `cx_Oracle.SYSDBA` mode:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('sys', 'password', dsn_tns, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
ok

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('sys', 'password', dsn_tns)
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

However, if you connect as user **system**, you mustn't use the `cx_Oracle.SYSDBA` mode:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('system', 'password', dsn_tns)
ok

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('system', 'password', dsn_tns, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

The difference of the users sys and system is explained for instance [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admqs/administering-user-accounts-and-security.html#GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5).