# Oracle SQL Developer fails to connect to Oracle Database while SQL*Plus works

Tags: oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, case-sensitive

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle database on a development server with my local Oracle SQL developer (17.4.1.054).
When I try to connect I get the following error: `ORA-0107: invalid username/password; logon denied`
Using the very same credentials on the sqlplus (after connection via ssh to the server) works perfectly fine.

The credentials are like: ORA/ora.

After thinking about it, I've other connections on same database with credentials like ora123/ora123 and ORA123/ORA123 that are working fine.

Is there any issue with case sensitive passwords in SQL developer?
Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Do you have a non-default role selected, maybe? Otherwise, are you sure you are actually connecting to the same database? Without seeing what you are doing, perhaps you use a TNS alias for SQL\*Plus and it isn't configured quite you expect, or something.

Comment: very same credentials on the sqlplus - where is this sqlplus you are running, on your development server or where your local SQLDev is? I'm betting you're talking to a different database

Comment: @AlexPoole: It is the same DB. For other user/schema it is working and can be verified by inserting data via sqlplus/SQLdeveloper and retrieving it with the other. sqlplus runns on the server. Connection setting are the same for other schemas/users(I connect via SSH to the server and type sqlplus, than the user than the passoword)

Comment: You enter the password when it prompts, not on the command line? That rules out my next guess, that the password has a $ symbol in it. Are there any special characters, or is it just letters? Presumably you've retyped it to rule out typos or extra whitespace. Hmm.

Comment: There are no special letters - I tried it several times - the password is really simple like ora (as it is a development environment that gets reset once a week).

Comment: One machine.  If in tnsnames.ora use HOST=localhost it works fine - if use the host name it does not

Comment: @KirkBates: sorry but I don't get this - could you explain that with more detail?

Comment: I understood from the phrase 'local SQL Developer'  that this is an all on one machine development environment - perhaps I may have assumed your set up was more like mine than it is.  But, just in case this helps, I have had great trouble getting SQL Developer to connect via TNS using a network alias, when other ways such as using a connect identifier, or Basic, or from SQLPlus, worked.  For me it turned out that it was related to running this test set up in a (Windows) Oracle Virtual Box VM with the 'Internal Network' networking option - changing this to 'Host-only' fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing database parameter **SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON** to **false** and they try login.

Comment: If login via SQL\*Plus works with the same credentials, this shouldn't be necessary, and just reduces the DB security?

Answer (score 0):

I think the clue is

> after connection via ssh to the server

Sounds to me like the problem is the network connection from your local machine to the database server, and not SQL Developer or SQL*Plus.

You can verify that by installing an [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html) with the SQL*Plus package on your local machine.

Comment: It's connecting to *something* though... just maybe not what they think.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't mean the network connection is faulty, just the way it is specified.

Comment: @wolφi: How could it be a connection problem if I get the ORA-0107: invalid username/password; logon denied?

Comment: @PaulEdison: if you ssh to the server, you can use other ways to connect to the database than if you use TNS via port 1521. Sorry for explaining it so poorly, I'm not a network guy. My guess is that in your case this TNS is not set up correctly. As for the error message: Oracle has a history of extremely unhelpful error messages, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812891/why-system-login-is-denied-in-cx-oracle-sysdba-mode/51051827#51051827) for example.

Comment: But it works for other users/schemas on the very same database - why it should not work only with one of them not that has different case passowrd than user name and not the matching ones.